# Calculate HMAC-SHA1 Signature using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, amazon-web-services, hmacsha1

I am writing a JavaScript Client Application that needs to communicate with Server. I tried to implement the API, but i stuck on one method and I need help.

Infect i don't know how to translate this from Java to JavaScript (I don't know where to find analog libraries written in javascript that are used in this method):

```
import java.security.SignatureException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
* This class defines common routines for generating
* authentication signatures for AWS requests.
*/
public class Signature {
 private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";


/**
* Computes RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
* * @param data
* The data to be signed.
* @param key
* The signing key.
* @return
* The Base64-encoded RFC 2104-compliant HMAC signature.
* @throws
* java.security.SignatureException when signature generation fails
*/
public static String calculateRFC2104HMAC(String data, String key)
throws java.security.SignatureException
{
   String result;
   try {

     // get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

   // get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
   Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
   mac.init(signingKey);

   // compute the hmac on input data bytes
   byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());

   // base64-encode the hmac
   result = Encoding.EncodeBase64(rawHmac);

   } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
   }
  return result;
 }
}
```

This method is from AWS Documentations: 
[Java Sample Code for Calculating HMAC-SHA1 Signatures](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AuthJavaSampleHMACSignature.html)

I am asking if someone can give me some references (websites) where I can find solution or analog libraries, written in javascript.

I searched AWS Documentation and SDK for JavaScript and I couldn't find translation in JS.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi i think this might be helpful for you.

Here you can find out the link to calculate hmac sha1:

http://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/

Here you can find the source code in javascript.

https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/releases/tag/v1.5.0